# Валидация значений в диалоге

Tags: android, java

У меня есть диалог ввода:

```
AlertDialog.Builder inputDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
EditText editText = new EditText(this.myContext); 
inputDialog.setView(editText); 
inputDialog.setTitle("Input Dialog"); 
inputDialog.setMessage("Input new value"); 
inputDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface _, int __) {
    String value = editText.getText() + "";
    // обработка значения
  }
});
inputDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface _, int __) {
  }
  }
});
inputDialog.show();
```

Как сделать, чтобы кнопка `OK` была недоступна при некоторых введенных пользователем значениях (из `editText`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так

```
Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

if (editText.getText() == "значение") {
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Эту проверку можно поместить в слушатель нажатий клавиш

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Проверять здесь
    }
});
```

либо добавить это все в текстовый фильтр

```
filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        // Проверять здесь
    }
});
```

Comment: Почему-то `dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1/2/3)` всегда возвращает `null`, хотя кнопки добавлены в диалог.

Comment: Точнее так: if (editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("значение")) {
...
}

Лучше сразу советовать как правильно, а то копипастишь и думаешь: "А что же не так?!"!

Comment: @DroidAlex, а вы не знаете, почему `getButton` всегда `null` возвращает? У меня пока не получилось получить кнопку.

Comment: А покажите полностью код вашего активити и код работы с диалогом. Подозреваю, что Вы отходите от стандартного протокола работы с диалогами в Андроид и создаете его сами, что не хорошо(то бишь не используете onCreateDialog()). Но это гадание на кофейной гуще. Вечером приду домой - посмотрюваш код, если кинете.

Comment: Я уже заставил его работать. Но я действительно нарушаю контракт работы с диалогами. А чем плохо не использование метода `onCreateDialog`? И почему активи должно знать про все диалоги. К тому же, я работаю с фрагментами.

Answer (score 1):

У AlertDialog есть метод getButton(int). просто получаете кнопку:

```
 Button btn = alertDiallog.getButtom(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
```

И делайте с кнопкой все что хотите.